# Android MediaRecorder Runtime Exception

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

Here is my code.

```
try {
                    if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
                        try {
                            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        // This line throwing exception
                        mMediaRecorder.start();

                        try {
                            if (mCamera != null)
                                mCamera.startSmoothZoom(globalZoomValue);
                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // This is thrown if the previous calls are not called with
                    // the
                    // proper order
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

This code working fine other device but throwing exception on samsung galaxy S2.

Comment: surround with try catch

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.

 at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)

 at com.youspeak.RecordStep1$9.handleMessage(RecordStep1.java:368)

 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)

 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)